# Internal server error message

Tags: entries

I'm getting the following internal server error message when I try and make a change on my website. It is only happening on one page!

file_get_contents(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=610+Bunker+Ave.+Kellogg%2C+Idaho+83837): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

Comment: Try adding quotes around the requested url? But... Do not forget `You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs.`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using some sort of Google Maps plugin on your site. Google recently started limiting access to their Maps API, and now you need a key to be able to make Maps requests.

Go here to request an API key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key. Then input the key into whatever plugin is using Google Maps. There should be a field in the plugin settings that asks for the key.